# Prepend character to key in PHP array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to convert a data source (`Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => 1 [3] =>...`) to use in json.  In my php page, I use `json_encode((object) $data)` (also works as `json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`) which yields an array that looks like: `{"0":false,"1":false,"2":true,"3":false,...}`.  I would like to add a character in front of the key, returning as `{"A0":false,"A1":false,"A2":true,"A3":false,...}`.  How do I go about doing so?
I have searched this forum and google extensively but am having no luck.  How do I prepend or concatenate a character to the key?

Comment: instead of indexed or numbered array use associative array.

Comment: `foreach($foo as $key => $value) { $new_foo['A'.$key] = $value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in PHP, then I would suggest to do any manipulation in PHP before `json_encode`ing.

Say your array is called `$arr`:

```
//Make array of new keys
$newKeys = array_map(function($k){return 'A'.$k;}, array_keys($arr));
//Combine new keys with value
$newArray = array_combine($newKeys, $arr);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Upvoted but it does not count because of my new status!  Many thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$source = [0 => 'bla', 1 => 'blop'];

// Get your keys
$keys = array_keys($source);

// Prepend whatever to each key
$formatted_keys = array_map(function ($key) {
    return 'A' . $key;
}, $keys);

// Build a new array using $formatted_keys for keys
// and array_values($source) for values.
$result = array_combine($formatted_keys, array_values($source));


http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php  
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php  
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the array keys like this:

```
foreach ($data  as $key=>$value)
{
    $data["A".$key] = $value;
    unset($data[$key]);
}
```